# Symbols é and á

Tags: c#

I'm developing the Windows Phone 7 prog.
And there's problem with symbols from the subject name. I want to use this C# code:

```
str="Santiago Bernabéu";
int i=str.IndexOf(é);
if(i!=-1)
str.Replace('é','e');
```

but in debug i=-1.

Please help me to solve this problem :)

P.S. I'm Russian and my English isn't good. Please, answer me in simple English :) thank you :)

P.P.S. thank you! but there's another problem: my prog downloads information, and symbols from subject's name in debug mode - '�'. Maybe it's coding trouble? Site with information which I need using UTF-8.

P.P.P.S.

There's downloading the sourcecode:

```
public string Adress
    {
        get
        {
            return _adr;
        }

        set
        {
            _adr = value.Substring(0, value.Length - 1);
            client.Encoding = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
            client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
            client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(_adr, UriKind.Absolute));
        }
}
```

Handler:

```
        void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
            return;
        _sourcecode = e.Result;
    }
```

Please, help :) it's last problem of functional part of project

Comment: Is there a pair of quotes around `é` in `str.IndexOf('é')`?

Comment: Yes, you got an encoding problem.  The '�' character is the substitution character for invalid encoding values.  You are not using the correct encoding when you read the data, probably because it isn't actually utf-8.  But you didn't post that code so that's only a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solve of this problem - using MSPToolkit

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me:

```
string str = "Santiago Bernabéu";
int i = str.IndexOf('é');

Console.WriteLine("i = {0}", i);

if(i != -1)
    str = str.Replace('é', 'e');

Console.WriteLine(str);
```

The output is:

> i = 15
>
> Santiago Bernabeu

Note that you need to do `str = str.Replace('é', 'e')` – the replacement does not happen in place.

Answer (score 0):

this probably depends on your system's locale. Try the following:

```
int i = str.IndexOf("é", StringComparison.InvariantCulture)
```

Nico